# git diff - highlight first line

Tags: git, diff

If I run `git diff` and have several files changed I find I get one long listing of the diffs with no clear separation between one diff and the next.

Is there any way to highlight the first line of a diff or have some visual marker between diff hunks?

Comment: like http://stackoverflow.com/a/28505651/6309?

Comment: you can always use git add -p to choose specific hunks

Comment: Take a look at `git difftool` in combination with a graphical diff viewer like `kompare` or `kdiff3`.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way that I found is to use a difftool.

I use meld. To start using it properly:

- install [meld](http://meldmerge.org/)
- configure meld as your default difftool

  `git config --global diff.tool meld`
- navigate to a git repository and start digging

  `git difftool`

You will then see a diff for each file separately